# Markdown does not display my mp4 local video

Tags: github, markdown

I wanted to display an **mp4 video** in my markdown file **README.md**. The video is in the same file as the README file I have tried several codes including:

```
![](ReactManageCourseApp.mp4)
```

and

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="ReactManageCourseApp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

none of those worked for me I did also add `./` but still not working. Check [here](https://github.com/DinaTaklit/React-Course-APP/blob/master/README.md) The video is not loading . How to fix that is there any way?

Comment: I remind that I have tried all the links shared and codes but still could not fix the probe. I remind also that I wanna show a local video not a youtube video where I can use iframe :p.

Comment: The two duplicates are still relevant. Please read them and adjust your expectations. You're not going to be able to embed an MP4 in your GitHub README.

Comment: Hmm ook Thank you.